# How to find out reference object id of an azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to automate the addition of azure virtual machines to azure ad security groups. 
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId   -RefObjectId

I am trying to find out the input for parameter -RefObjectId but no luck.

Is there a way to find out the refrence objectid of an azure virtual machine?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, you want to add vm to the security group? is that even possible?

Comment: @blan Could you please share some more details on what you want to achieve, by adding the VM to a security group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable MSI for the VM, then it will generate a service principal, I suppose you want to add the service principal of the VM to the AAD security group.

Follow the doc to [enable MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm#enable-system-assigned-managed-identity-on-an-existing-vm), then navigate to your VM ->  `Identity`, you will see the `Object ID`, that is the property you need to pass to `-RefObjectId`.

Answer (score 0):

@Joy wang

Thanks, that worked. apparently, i didnot automate identity on on the machines. I modified the arm script to turn on the identity on and i took the id from the output of
Get-AzureADserviceprincipal -searchstring "vmname"